# Inserting rows of data into 2 SQL tables by using a primary and foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database where I've built 2 tables: **"client_info"**, and **"client_hobbies"**.
In *client_info*, there are 3 columns: `client_id`, `client_firstname`, and `client_lastname`. In *client_hobbies* there are 2 columns: `client_id` and `hobby`.

I've made the `client_id` in the `client_info` table the primary and a surrogate key. And I've made the `client_id` in the 2nd table the reference key to the first table. I want to write a statement/statements where I can insert into both tables by using the `client_id`.

For example: I want to insert new clients, and at the same time insert their hobby.

Huge thanks you to anyone that can help me. I am using **MS SQL Server 2014**.

Comment: You might want to look into views and triggers on views, if you want to do the insert in one step.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 commands separated by semicolon:

```
INSERT INTO client_info (client_id, client_firstname, client_lastname)
VALUES (@client_id, @client_firstname, @client_lastname);
INSERT INTO client_hobbies (client_id, hobby)
VALUES (@client_id, @hobby);
```